# what exactly is haswidgets and widgets in bolt (or twig rather )?

Tags: twig, bolt-cms

I was just going through the Default theme of bolt CMS, and i came actoss the following lines of code:

```
{% if haswidgets('aside_top') %}

        {{ widgets('aside_top') }}

 {% else %}
```

I googled `twig haswidgets` and also `twig widgets` , but i could't find anything.

can somebody explain what these two methods are ? and what exactly do they do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are a feature of Bolt. Extensions can push content to specific places in the backend and also to some places in the frontend, as long as the theme supports that. They are called widgets. the `haswidgets()` and `widgets()` twig functions are for checking and displaying them.

You can find more info here https://docs.bolt.cm/3.1/templating/widgets and here https://docs.bolt.cm/3.1/extensions/intermediate/widgets